# Getting files from remote windows pc into linux pc using command line

Tags: linux, samba

Trying to copy files from remote windows pc into my local linux using shell script.
Can someone please tell me how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `smbclient` to connect to the windows shared directory:

```
smbclient -L <ip address> -U <windows user>
```

Alternatively, you can mount a shared directory using `smb mount`:

```
mkdir /mnt/local_share
sudo mount -t cifs //<ip address/<shared directory> /mnt/local_share
```